# How do I define x and y rows/colums from a csv?

Tags: gnuplot

I've got a file like this:

```
Date first second third
01-08 30 22 161
01-10 23 20 104
01-12 50 16 79
01-14 67 21 99
02-08 37 33 155
02-10 48 44 66
02-12 89 12 91
```

How do I use the date column as x-axis and the dates as x-ticks and the values of the columns of first, second and third as bars. Each of the three value of one date should be a group of 3 bars with one x-tick -> the date:

```
   |     |         |
   |     |         |
40 -     |         |
   |   | |         |
20 -   |||       |||
   |___|||_______|||_____etc.
   01-08     01-10
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Histogram plot style using thin solid fill boxes
set style histogram cluster gap 3
set style data histogram
set style fill solid
set boxwidth 0.5

#Use column headers for title
set key autotitle columnhead

plot 'file.dat' using 2:xticlabel(1), 'file.dat' using 3, 'file.dat' using 4
```

[image]